Deployment failure in wildfly 31
I am trying to deploy my war file in wildfly 31 server and getting some signature verifier issue in microsoft-windowsazure-api jar. The same war file is working in jboss. The reported jar downloaded from maven. if delete the .sf,.rsf files then deployments goes fine but not sure why i am facing this issue in wildfly 31 alone. I have pasted the error message details below. Please guide me how to resolve this issue.
2024-07-10 13:00:38,336 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0003: Could not index class com/microsoft/schemas/_2003/_10/serialization/ObjectFactory.class at /C:/UTP_PACK/UTP-REL-R202403-RET-2024.03.24-01-5108-saf-retailsuite-developer-s08/TTTT/jboss/bin/content/ResourceServer.war/WEB-INF/lib/microsoft-windowsazure-api-0.4.6.jar: java.lang.SecurityException: SHA1 digest error for com/microsoft/schemas/_2003/_10/serialization/ObjectFactory.class
at java.base/sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier.verify(ManifestEntryVerifier.java:256)
at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:252)
at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:239)
at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierStream.read(JarVerifier.java:484)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271)
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
at io.smallrye.jandex//org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.verifyMagic(Indexer.java:2090)
at io.smallrye.jandex//org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.indexWithSummary(Indexer.java:2485)
at io.smallrye.jandex//org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:2458)
at org.jboss.as.server@23.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:82)
at org.jboss.as.server@23.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:34)
at org.jboss.as.server@23.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
at org.jboss.msc@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1617)
at org.jboss.msc@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1580)
at org.jboss.msc@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1438)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Thanks
M.Selvakumar
I have to deploy the war file in wildfly 31 and what should be done to resolve the reported problem.
